# Sending multiple parameters to stored procedure with jQuery Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I've got a web method that looks like:

```
[WebMethod]
        public void InsertDrugNameAndColorToDatabase(string drugName,string drugColor)
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("spInsertDrugText", con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drugName", drugName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drugColor", drugColor);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
```

and a little JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".drugQuizzes").draggable({ tolerance: "fit" });
            $(".drugAnswers").droppable({
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    var drugName = JSON.stringify({ "drugName": $(ui.draggable).find("span").text() });
                    var drugColor = JSON.stringify({ "drugColor": $(ui.draggable).css("background-color") });
                    console.log(drugColor);
                    console.log(drugName);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "SendDrugName.asmx/InsertDrugNameToDatabase",
                        data: drugName,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            //response(data.d);
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            console.log(xhr.status);
                            console.log(thrownError);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".drugQuizzes").draggable({ tolerance: "fit" });
            $(".drugAnswers").droppable({
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    var drugName = JSON.stringify({ "drugName": $(ui.draggable).find("span").text() });
                    var drugColor = JSON.stringify({ "drugColor": $(ui.draggable).css("background-color") });
                    console.log(drugColor);
                    console.log(drugName);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "SendDrugName.asmx/InsertDrugNameToDatabase",
                        data: drugName,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            //response(data.d);
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            console.log(xhr.status);
                            console.log(thrownError);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I have a version of the stored procedure ans JS where only one parameter is sent to the stored procedure, and that works.
From the console.log(drugName) and console.log(drugColor) I get

```
{"drugColor":"rgb(255, 69, 0)"} 
{"drugName":"ORACEA"}
```

How can I make the `data` parameter of the ajax call take multiple parameters at once?
What are some names of general techniques that I need to be aware of for sending more than one parameter to a stored procedure at once using jQuery ajax?

Comment: Send the parameters back as properties of a single object, or as separate values in a single array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider building an object literal on the client-side and passing that entire object to the service, thus you have one parameter in your service call, like this:

Client-side:

```
var myData = {};
myData.DrugName' = $(ui.draggable).find("span").text();
myData.DrugColor' = $(ui.draggable).css("background-color");

// Create a data transfer object (DTO) with the proper structure, which is what we will pass to the service.
var DTO = { 'theData' : myData };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "SendDrugName.asmx/InsertDrugNameToDatabase",
    data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        //response(data.d);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(thrownError);
    }
});
```

Now on the service-side, you will need to build a class that represents the contents of the object literal created above, like this:

```
public class ServiceData
{
    public string DrugName { get; set; }
    public string DrugColor { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, change your web service code to accept one parameter, like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public void InsertDrugNameAndColorToDatabase(ServiceData theData)
{
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("spInsertDrugText", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drugName", theData.DrugName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drugColor", theData.DrugColor);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The data passed from the jQuery call is automatically matched up with the class properties you have in your `ServiceData` class as long as the names match on both the client-side and server-side.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify multiple data items like:

```
data: 'drugName='+ drugName  + '&drugColor=' + drugColor;
```

Comment: This becomes unwieldy on both the service side and client-side, as the number of parameters grows.

Comment: What techniques would be more extensible?  Say, if there were 10 parameters to the stored procedure?  Would you create an object like you could in C# with whatever properties?  How would you send all of those properties of a particular object at the same time? (I do appreciate the quick and dirty, too, though).

Comment: @wootscootinboogie check my answer - that's exactly what it does.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - your answer solves half the problem, sort of. You will still end up with a list of parameters on the service side, one for each value you are passing in your object literal.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to stringify it at all, you can pass the parameters as an object. Try this:

```
$(".drugAnswers").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "SendDrugName.asmx/InsertDrugNameToDatabase",
            data: {
                'drugName': $(ui.draggable).find("span").text(),
                'drugColor': $(ui.draggable).css("background-color")
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                //response(data.d);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(xhr.status);
                console.log(thrownError);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The `ajax()` function will then stringify it for you and pass it across to your C# endpoint.

Comment: This becomes unwieldy on the service side, as the number of parameters grows.

Comment: @KarlAnderson sounds like a code organization issue in the service to me.

Comment: @KarlAnderson you could convert the action to take a `Dictionary<string,string>` which you then loop through to populate the SP paramaters. However, the OP was asking how he could send multiple params in the `data` attribute of his `ajax` call so I didn't include it in the answer. Feel free to add one yourself if you feel it beneficial to the OP.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with AJAX to know if this is going to work offhand, but it looks nice.  +1 if it works after testing.